# Null pointer exception in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have the attached exception when I try to make a ExpandableListView

can anyone help!

[image]

this is my method

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View childView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            childView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.side_menu_child_view,null);
        } else {
            childView = convertView;
        }

        TextView linkName       = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.child_title_text);
        LinkEntity linkEntity   = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        linkName.setText(linkEntity.getDisplayName(true));
        return childView;
    }
```

this is the xml of my list

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandable_side_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:childDivider="@null"
    android:childIndicator="@null"
    android:divider="@drawable/side_menu_separator"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: stacktrace never references any of your classes, and fails to render the divider, did you set a custom divider in xml?

Comment: I have updated the post with xml, but the exception is coming from getChildView, the list is already shown but when I press the group item to show it's childs I got the exception

Comment: set this for your child divider @drawable/side_menu_separator

Comment: Thanks Piyush Gupta, it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by set divider to my child divider instead of null, I don't know why, but thanks all any way

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

And put this line above the `if` statement:

```
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Where `mInflater` is declared as a class variable like so `LayoutInflater mInflater;`

See if this works.

Comment: I have tried it before and it doesn't work, actually I have changed it after reading this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730422/cannot-understand-nullpointerexception-with-custom-adapter

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to your ExapndableListview 
android:divider="@null"